# Creating Tic-Tac-Toe in C - array not showing changes, not returning error messages

Tags: c

I am trying to create a tic-tac-toe game in C.

My instructions are as follows:

Write a C program that lets two people play tic-tac-toe. Use a global array: `char ttt[3][3];` to represent the board state, and globals for the player (a char to hold X or O or whatever you characters you want), i and j integers for indexes, and an integer to count the number of moves completed. Show the game board for each move two characters for the players with a key for the user to type one character or digit to say what spot to take in the board. At the end of a game, say who won or that it is a tie. Have at least the functions to print the board, get a valid move, and check for a win; do use printf, scanf, if-else, switch (to find indexes into ttt) while, for.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

// Global array for the board

char ttt[3][3] = {
    {'1', '2', '3'},
    {'4', '5', '6'},
    {'7', '8', '9'}

};

void PrintTheBoard() { // Print the board as it currently is

    printf("| %c | | %c | | %c |\n", ttt[0][0], ttt[0][1], ttt[0][2]);
    printf("| %c | | %c | | %c |\n", ttt[1][0], ttt[1][1], ttt[1][2]);
    printf("| %c | | %c | | %c |\n", ttt[2][0], ttt[2][1], ttt[2][2]);

}

// Check for a win

int CheckForWin() {

    // Checks for horizontal win conditions

    if (ttt[0][0] == ttt[0][1] && ttt[0][1] == ttt[0][2])
        return 1;
    else if (ttt[1][0] == ttt[1][1] && ttt[1][1] == ttt[1][2])
        return 1;
    else if (ttt[2][0] == ttt[2][1] && ttt[2][1] == ttt[2][2])
        return 1;

    // Checks for vertical wins

    else if (ttt[0][0] == ttt[1][0] && ttt[1][0] == ttt[2][0])
        return 1;
    else if (ttt[0][1] == ttt[1][1] && ttt[1][1] == ttt[2][1])
        return 1;
    else if (ttt[0][2] == ttt[1][2] && ttt[1][2] == ttt[2][2])
        return 1;

    // Checks for diagonal wins

    else if (ttt[0][0] == ttt[1][1] && ttt[1][1] == ttt[2][2])
        return 1;
    else if (ttt[0][2] == ttt[1][1] && ttt[1][1] == ttt[2][0])
        return 1;

    else if (ttt[0][0] != '1' && ttt[0][1] != '2' && ttt[0][2] != '3' &&
             ttt[1][0] != '4' && ttt[1][1] != '5' && ttt[1][2] != '6' &&
             ttt[2][0] != '7' && ttt[2][1] != '8' && ttt[2][2] != '9')
        return 2;
    else
        return 0;

}

int main() { // The function below gets a move, validates it, and keep tracks of the # of moves made.

    int choice;
    int player = 1;
    int i;
    int counter = 0;
    char mark;
    int isValid;    

    // Gets user input

    do {

    PrintTheBoard();

    player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;

    printf("Player %d, enter a number:  ", player);
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    // Determines what mark to make, depending on the current player by way of "if current player is player 1, use X, otherwise, use O"

    mark = (player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';

    /*

    The below switch function is a bit convoluted. Depending on the value of the "choice" variable (1-9, chosen by the active player
    and corresponding to a position on the board), the value is checked for position validity by checking if the position in the
    array corresponding to the choice still has its original numeral value, which indicates the spot is not taken.

    If it still has that original value, the position is assigned an X or an O depending on the current player.

    If the spot is taken, indicated by the value not being equal to its original numeral, the player is told that the position is
    invalid.

    If the player does not choose a valid case, the player is informed of this and told what to do.

    */

    switch(choice) {

        case 1:
            if (ttt[0][0] == '1') {
                ttt[0][0] = mark;
            }

        break;

        case 2:
            if (ttt[0][1] == '2') {
                ttt[0][1] = mark;
            }

        break;

        case 3:
            if (ttt[0][2] == '3') {
                ttt[0][2] = mark;
            }

        break;

        case 4:
            if (ttt[1][0] == '4') {
                ttt[1][0] = mark;
            }

        break;

        case 5:
            if (ttt[1][1] == '5') {
                ttt[1][1] = mark;
            }

        break;

        case 6:
            if (ttt[1][2] == '6') {
                ttt[1][2] = mark;
            }

        break;

        case 7:
            if (ttt[2][0] == '7') {
                ttt[2][0] = mark;
        }
        break;

        case 8:
            if (ttt[2][1] == '8') {
                ttt[2][1] = mark;
            }

        break;

        case 9:
            if (ttt[2][2] == '9') {
                ttt[2][2] = mark;
            }
        break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid input. Please choose and type a number 1-9 corresponding to a position that is not already taken.\n");
            printf("Press any key to continue.\n");
            player--;
            getch();

        }


    i = CheckForWin();


    if (i != 1 && i != 2)
        player++;

    } while (i == 0);

    PrintTheBoard();

    if (i == 1) 
        printf("Player %d wins!", player);
    else
        printf("The game is a draw!");

}
```

My issue is that the error message is not printed when the two players choose the same spot. The program then goes to the next players turn, effectively skipping the player who chose an occupied spot. The player who occupied the spot in question keeps the spot.

Furthermore, I don't really understand how to use i and j integers to fill out the indexes. When I try code blocks previously used for this, tons of errors show up.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Small tip: instead using 9 switch cases you can directly convert between grid numbers and indices with some modulo math

Comment: @meowgoesthedog the assignment requires switch statements, so I'll keep them in my submitted file, but I'm curious to know how that would work.

Comment: It seems like you expect execution to jump from the end of an `if` statement in one of the other cases, to the `default` case? That isn't how switch...case works.  The `default` case is only entered if none of the other `case:` cases were entered.

Comment: add `else` statement for each of your `if` in `switch`. that will be your error

Comment: @M.M how would I implement the content of the `default` case in each case to avoid skipping? I tried just copypasting the content of `default` inside an else statement tagged on to every case's `if` but it made things super wonky. Edit: I put everything inside brackets on each else statement and it works perfectly now.

Comment: @SOMEK you could tag on an `else invalid_move = true;` or something like that to each `if`, and then have the error message case after the loop where you test the `invalid_move` variable, which would avoid having quite so much copy and pasting

Comment: The only thing in the `case` statement should be assigning a value to `i` and `j`. Then you can check the value `ttt[i][j]` to determine whether someone already played there, and either display an error and loop back to get a new input, or make that player's move if the input is valid. You should be running the same code whatever the values of `i` and `j` are.

Comment: @TimRandall I don't really understand what you're trying to say. Though the instructions said to use i and j to make the array thing happen, I wasn't able to figure it out and so just manually created the values. I'm still trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Instead of code that says `if (ttt[2][1] == '8') {ttt[2][1] = mark;}` you want something more like `i=2;j=1;... if (ttt[i][j] == choice) {ttt[i][j] = mark;}else{printf("Invalid...` Just put a value of 0, 1, or 2 into `i` and `j` and use the variables where your current code has numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an extra boolean variable and moving the error message *outside* of the `switch`:

```
int okay = 0;

switch (choice) {
case 1:
    if (ttt[0][0] == '1') {
        ttt[0][0] = mark;
        okay = 1;
    }
    break;

case 2:
    if (ttt[0][1] == '2') {
        ttt[0][1] = mark;
        okay = 1;
    }
    break;

case 3:
    if (ttt[0][2] == '3') {
        ttt[0][2] = mark;
        okay = 1;
    }
    break;

case 4:
    if (ttt[1][0] == '4') {
        ttt[1][0] = mark;
        okay = 1;
    }
    break;

case 5:
    if (ttt[1][1] == '5') {
        ttt[1][1] = mark;
        okay = 1;
    }
    break;

case 6:
    if (ttt[1][2] == '6') {
        ttt[1][2] = mark;
        okay = 1;
    }
    break;

case 7:
    if (ttt[2][0] == '7') {
        ttt[2][0] = mark;
        okay = 1;
    }
    break;

case 8:
    if (ttt[2][1] == '8') {
        ttt[2][1] = mark;
        okay = 1;
    }
    break;

case 9:
    if (ttt[2][2] == '9') {
        ttt[2][2] = mark;
        okay = 1;
    }
    break;
}

if (! okay) {
    printf("Invalid input. Please choose and type a number 1-9 corresponding to a position that is not already taken.\n");
    printf("Press any key to continue.\n");
    player--;
    getch();
}
```

---

With a bit of trickery, we can make this a bit more compact:

```
int savemark = mark;

switch (choice) {
case 1:
    if (ttt[0][0] == '1') {
        ttt[0][0] = mark++;
    }
    break;

case 2:
    if (ttt[0][1] == '2') {
        ttt[0][1] = mark++;
    }
    break;

case 3:
    if (ttt[0][2] == '3') {
        ttt[0][2] = mark++;
    }
    break;

case 4:
    if (ttt[1][0] == '4') {
        ttt[1][0] = mark++;
    }
    break;

case 5:
    if (ttt[1][1] == '5') {
        ttt[1][1] = mark++;
    }
    break;

case 6:
    if (ttt[1][2] == '6') {
        ttt[1][2] = mark++;
    }
    break;

case 7:
    if (ttt[2][0] == '7') {
        ttt[2][0] = mark++;
    }
    break;

case 8:
    if (ttt[2][1] == '8') {
        ttt[2][1] = mark++;
    }
    break;

case 9:
    if (ttt[2][2] == '9') {
        ttt[2][2] = mark++;
    }
    break;
}

if (mark == savemark) {
    printf("Invalid input. Please choose and type a number 1-9 corresponding to a position that is not already taken.\n");
    printf("Press any key to continue.\n");
    player--;
    getch();
}
```

---

You mentioned that you *must* use a `switch` but expressed the desire to see the more compact solution. So, here's a way:

```
int okay = 0;

do {
    if (choice < 1)
        break;

    if (choice > 9)
        break;

    choice -= 1;

    if (ttt[choice / 3][choice % 3] == ('1' + choice)) {
        ttt[choice / 3][choice % 3] = mark;
        okay = 1;
    }
} while (0);

if (! okay) {
    printf("Invalid input. Please choose and type a number 1-9 corresponding to a position that is not already taken.\n");
    printf("Press any key to continue.\n");
    player--;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this `if (ttt[(choice - 1) / 3][(choice - 1) % 3] == '0' + choice) { ttt[choice/3][choice%3] = mark; okay = 1; }` simpler ?

Comment: @KamilCuk From the top comments [AFAICT], OP _must_ use the `switch`, so I left it in. But, yes, it's a bit verbose/ugly.

Comment: @KamilCuk Since OP wanted [as extra credit], a solution similar to yours, I've added one. It requires a range check on `choice` which you didn't have [and was not required with the `switch`]. Your indexing was correct for the `if` but was incorrect for the assignment. I fixed that. And, I predecremented `choice` so the code could be simplified.

Comment: @CraigEstey what does predecrementing and adding '1' to choice do for the calculations?

Comment: Kamilcuk's `if` and assignment used [or _should_ have used] `choice - 1` in _four_ places. By predecrementing, we can replace those with `choice`. `'1'` compensates for the predecrement when the original value was needed